# Haskell polymorphic function to convert between algebraic data types

Tags: function, haskell, types

I have two haskell functions, which convert between two algebraic data types.

```
data Ab = A | B
data Cd = C | D

fromAb :: Ab -> Cd
fromAb A = C
fromAb B = D

toAb :: Cd -> Ab
toAb C = A
toAb D = B
```

But I would like to make a polymorph function, that takes both algebraic data types and converts between them.

```
foo A = C
foo B = D
foo C = A
foo D = B
```

But Haskell deduces from "foo A = C" that the function is

```
foo :: Ab -> Cd
```

I tried to make the data types instances of a class to make foo polymorph but it didn't work.

```
class Abcd a
instance Abcd Ab
instance Abcd Cd

foo :: Abcd a => a -> Ab
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is very natural with `TypeFamilies`. You define a type-level function

```
type family Converted a
type instance Converted Ab = Cd
type instance Converted Cd = Ab
```

Then your signature becomes

```
foo :: a -> Converted a
```

If you just were fiddling with types you'd be done, but since you want to have different behavior on the value level (returning an `A` from a `C` and so on) we actually need to spread our cases across instances of a new type class:

```
class Convertable a where
    foo :: a -> Converted a

instance Convertable Ab where
    foo A = C
    foo B = D

instance Convertable Cd where
    foo C = A
    foo D = B
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b90191895c893bd5))

Finally, you might consider making `Converted` a closed type synonym family if using recent GHC, or make it "associated" by moving the instances inside the `Convertable` instance declarations.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the signature in your last code fragment there is still wrong. It wouldn't be `foo :: Abcd a => a -> Ab`, since if `a ~ Ab` then the function should be returning a `Cd`, not an `Ab`.

There are a few different ways of doing what you want. First, recognize that what you're trying to do is express a common set of behavior based not on a type, but on a relationship *between* two types. This is basically the purpose of a multi-parameter typeclass (which is probably the simplest way to accomplish this).

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
data Ab = A | B
data Cd = C | D

fromAb :: Ab -> Cd
fromAb A = C
fromAb B = D

toAb :: Cd -> Ab
toAb C = A
toAb D = B

class Iso a b where
  to :: a -> b

instance Iso Ab Cd where
  to = fromAb

instance Iso Cd Ab where
  to = toAb
```

EDIT: Note that my answer is completely equivalent to jberryman's, which uses type families. This is what I mean by "a few ways of doing what you want."

Comment: Fundeps would probably be what op wants: `class Iso a b | a -> b`, and this would be the traditional approach to this (pre-type families).

Comment: fundeps wouldn't actually be necessary for this case since `to` uses both types of the instance. It would prevent you from adding new types to this "interconvertible" group of types.

Comment: Sorry my comment wasn't very clear. I mean that type inference would be nicer with fundeps, either `a -> b` (which would be equivalent to TypeFamilies) or `a -> b, b -> a`. As written e.g. `to A` would be ambiguous, I believe.

Comment: No, you're correct, and adding fundeps certainly isn't *wrong*, but it's expressing a property that may or may not be desirable depending on the application. If we add `data Ef` later, there's no reason we can't convert arbitrarily between the 3 types using `to` by declaring the appropriate instances. If we use a fundep, though, this becomes impossible, but of course with the added benefit of simpler type inference if we don't need that flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the extensions `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

data Ab = A | B deriving (Show)
data Cd = C | D deriving (Show)

class Convert a b | a -> b where
  convert :: a -> b

instance Convert Ab Cd where
  convert A = C
  convert B = D

instance Convert Cd Ab where
  convert C = A
  convert D = B
```

Demo:

```
λ> convert A
C
λ> convert B
D
λ> convert C
A
λ> convert D
B
```