# Haskell: Conversions of polymorphic types

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc, data-conversion, type-level-computation

I wanted to write a library that can convert types between various isomorphic formats and from "subtypes" to "supertypes", for example using the following isomorphisms and injections:

`(a, (b, c))` <~> `((a, b), c)`

`(Either a (Either b c))` <~> `(Either (Either a b) c)`

`(a, ())` <~> `a` <~> `((), a)`

`(Either a Void)` <~> `a` <~> `(Either Void a)`

`(a, Void)` <~> `Void` <~> `(Void, a)`

`((a, b) -> c)` <~> `a -> (b -> c)`

`(() -> c)` <~> c

`(a, Either x y)` <~> `Either (a, x) (a, y)`

`(Either x y, a)` <~> `Either (x, a) (y, a)`

`a` ~> `x -> a` (Constant function)

`Int` ~> `Integer`

`Int` ~> `Double`

`a` ~> `()`

… and nested combinations of that.

It works (by transforming the input type into a canonical isomorphic form, deeply applying the subtype injections and than de-canonicalizing to the result type), but mostly only for monotypes. Using a polymorphic type in a position that is reachable in the tree of type constructors going only through the constructors `(->)`, `Either` and `(,)` will lead to an "Ambiguous Type" error message because the overlapping type classes that determine which transformations are applied cannot be resolved, and that is good, because the type variable *could* possibly be instantiated to for example a pair type, and ignoring this would make the whole transformation incoherent.

How can I constrain a Type variable to be neither of the form `(a -> b)` nor of the form `(a, b)` nor of the form `(Either a b)`? I tried this:

```
class BinaryTC tc x (r::Bool) a b | tc x a b -> r
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (r~'False) => BinaryTC tc (tc a b) r a b
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (r~'True) => BinaryTC tc x r a b

type NotHaskGenerating x = (
  ForallV (BinaryTC (,) x 'False),
  ForallV (BinaryTC (->) x 'False),
  ForallV (BinaryTC Either x 'False)
 )
```

in order to constrain the polymorphic type variables, but it does not work, not even in the canonicalization stage. This is because the information contained in a `ForallV` constraint is apparently only available by instantiating it via the `instV` function, and this must be done manually at the expression level. Is there any way to teach GHC to automatically use the information of a `Forall` constraint? An alternative would be to wrap each value in the `Identity` functor, but I would prefer to be able to put a constraint on the variables.

Comment: Note that `Iso'` and `Prism'` by the `lens` library implement isomorphisms and embeddings, the latter of which also allow going `Maybe` back. An iso and a prism can even be composed, as functions, into a prism!

Comment: Note that all the isomorphisms mentioned above do _not_ involve polymorphic types, in contrast with the title. Indeed, there is no `forall` in such types. A polymorphic iso could be e.g. Yoneda's `(forall r. (a->r)->r) <~> a`. However, the above isos are between monomorphic simple types, parameterized over a few type variables.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39417445/791604). Even if you get over this hurdle, you're going to find there's others to follow, e.g. normalizing both `((), a)` and `(a, ())` to the normalization of `a` in a sensible way. I wouldn't be surprised if there were further hurdles beyond. If this is just an exercise, have fun; but if you plan to use this for something, have you considered making the isomorphisms more explicit and only using the typeclass mechanism for stuff that it's good at...?

Comment: My motivation was that I wanted to compose morphisms in a non-strict monoidal category where the codomain of the first morphism is not the domain of the second, but is naturally isomorphic to it via some combination of the associator and the unitors and their inverses. Then I got carried away a little bit and included the other conversions. For my original problem, it is acceptable to wrap all "elementary" objects into Identity functors, because I can define the morphisms generating the monoidal category to expect these and then I do not have to care about them when composing the morphisms.

Comment: @chi: I didn't mean to say the isomorphisms would involve polymorphic types, but rather that I want to convert between polymorphic types using these isomorphisms. A polymorphic type *is* a type parameterized by type variable, or example the type of `2 :: forall a. (Num a)=>a`, Yoneda's iso has already a rank-2-type. If I used `2` in the type I want to convert in a place that the recursion descends to, it would yield an ambiguity error, because it is polymorphic and the type variable might be instantiated to something that the recursion could further descend into (e.g. a `Num` inst for pairs).

Comment: @BenjaminBerger Maybe it's just a matter of terminology, and it's not that important, but I'd think you want a polymorphic isomorphism (or, if you prefer, a natural isomorphism), rather than an isomorphism between polymorphic types (which would be higher ranked, as you mentioned). Anyway, the text of the question is clear, and mine is only a very minor point about terminology.